# Workflow step is failing after upgrade from AEM6.1 to AEM6.3

Tags: aem

We just upgraded from AEM6.1 to 6.3. I am trying to execute a workflow but getting the below error-

```
07.08.2017 15:20:21.233 *ERROR* [sling-threadpool-cc7c6ae7-7243-4db2-9490-b0810d422592-(apache-sling-job-thread-pool)-282-Granite Workflow Queue(com/adobe/granite/workflow/job/etc/workflow/models/content-request-for-deletion/jcr_content/model)] com.adobe.granite.repository.impl.SlingRepositoryImpl Bundle com.adobe.granite.workflow.core is NOT whitelisted to use SlingRepository.loginAdministrative
07.08.2017 15:20:21.233 *ERROR* [sling-threadpool-cc7c6ae7-7243-4db2-9490-b0810d422592-(apache-sling-job-thread-pool)-282-Granite Workflow Queue(com/adobe/granite/workflow/job/etc/workflow/models/content-request-for-deletion/jcr_content/model)] com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.JobHandler Error executing workflow step
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error logging in as service user
    at com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.util.ServiceLoginUtil.getWorkflowPayloadSession(ServiceLoginUtil.java:82)
    at com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.util.ServiceLoginUtil.getWorkflowPayloadWorkflowSession(ServiceLoginUtil.java:127)
    at com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.JobHandler.process(JobHandler.java:203)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.JobConsumerManager$JobConsumerWrapper.process(JobConsumerManager.java:500)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.JobQueueImpl.startJob(JobQueueImpl.java:291)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.JobQueueImpl.access$100(JobQueueImpl.java:58)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.JobQueueImpl$1.run(JobQueueImpl.java:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.jcr.LoginException: Bundle com.adobe.granite.workflow.core is NOT whitelisted
    at org.apache.sling.jcr.base.AbstractSlingRepository2.loginAdministrative(AbstractSlingRepository2.java:378)
    at com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.util.ServiceLoginUtil.getWorkflowPayloadSession(ServiceLoginUtil.java:76)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

Do I need to create a service user? How can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find useful this link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-5135
loginAdministrative is a deprecated method which you can still use, although in 6.3 an extra security level was added so in order to be able to use it you would need to create an OSGi config 
org.apache.sling.jcr.base.internal.LoginAdminWhitelist.fragment More info [here](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/service-authentication.html#whitelisting-bundles-for-administrative-login)

Answer (score 0):

This problem occur when we try to access resource resolver by administrative services in aem 6.3 or abouve version ...you can remove this error by following way

**Apache Sling Service User Mapper Service**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZwrU.png)

There are two options in this configurations:
Service mappings: The service mappings configuration can be used here.
You can configure it like this:
Bundle-Symbolic-Name: Sub-Service[Optional] = System-User-Name

Default User: If there is no service mapping corresponding to a bundle, then the bundle will pick default User and use it as it’s service authentication user.So if you don't want to provide any service mappings, you can use the option of default user.But it is not specific to the bundle.

2. Apache Sling Service User Mapper Amendment

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwpA8.png)

his configuration is used when you want to have an individual configuration for a particular project.
 If there are more than one configurations correspond to a particular bundle, based on the ranking, service can be picked.(The highest the number will be having highest ranking).

New loginService methods

Now the new methods are introduced to replace loginAdministrative methods:
ResourceResolver getServiceResourceResolver(Map authenticationInfo) throws LoginException;
Session loginService(String serviceInfo, String workspace) throws LoginException, RepositoryException;

Note: Each bundle using the ResourceResolverFactory or SlingRepository service actually gets an instance bound to the using bundle. That bundle is used to identify the service.